# Тестирование junit клиентской части клиент-серверного приложения

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть клиент-серверное приложение.

Для тестирования сервера я использовал in-memory базу данных, а вот с тестированием клиента у меня возникли проблемы.

Соединяется с сервером он с помощью `RestTemplate`, следовательно, протестировать у меня получается клиент только при запущенном сервере, а это, наверное, не совсем правильно. Да и потом, тестируется клиент у меня в таком случае на рабочей базе данных, а не на in-memory, это точно не хорошо.

Каким образом мне стоит проводить тестирование клиентской части?

Вот, к примеру, есть у меня метод в Сервис-слое клиента:

```
public class WebAppDepartmentsService {

    private final String HOST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/server/departments";

    @Override
    public void delete(String departmentName){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String uri = "/remove/department/{departmentName}";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("departmentName", departmentName);
        restTemplate.postForLocation(HOST_URL + uri, Department.class, map);
    }
}
```

И сейчас он тестируется вот так:

```
public class WebAppDepartmentsServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void testDelete(){
        departmentService = new WebAppDepartmentsService();
        departmentService.delete("QA");
        List<Department> departments = departmentService.getAll();
        assertEquals(5, departments.size());
    }
}
```

P.S Если можно, то хотелось бы конкретный пример тестирования для представленного мной метода `delete();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При написании юнит-тестов на клиенте, держать запущенный сервер излишне - достаточно просто перед запуском тестов "мокать" сервер, а после выполнения запроса проверять, что были выполнены нужные запросы. Но для этого необходимо будет немного переработать методы клиента, а именно: не создавать `RestTemplate` руками. Вместо этого можно внедрять его как зависимость через `@Autowired`:

```
@Service
public class WebAppDepartmentsServiceImpl implements WebAppDepartmentsService {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public WebAppDepartmentsServiceImpl(@Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    ...
}
```

После этого в тестовом классе создаете сервер для вашего `RestTemplate`:

```
public class WebAppDepartmentsServiceTest {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    private WebAppDepartmentsService departmentService = 
                new WebAppDepartmentsServiceImpl(restTemplate);

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }


    @Test
    public void testDelete() {
        // given
        mockServer
            .expect(requestTo("/remove/department/QA"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(
                "{\"id\" : \"42\"}", 
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        // when
        departmentService.delete("QA");

        // then
        mockServer.verify();
    }

    ...
}
```